# JQuery moving partialy displaying image as it enters the frame

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

This is rather obscure question, so I hope I can describe it well.

I have a frame in the top middle part of screen with few simple animations.
I would like to load an image (lets say cloud) that would be animated from left to right. But I would like that cloud to be displayed within the frame only.

The only solution I can think of is to create 2 divs on sides with higher z-index. However that seems like a dirty solution and extends the overall width of website. Not to mention the limitation of loaded images to the size of those eclipse divs.

Comment: just put them inside a div with `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
#clouddiv { overflow: hidden; }
```